# GPIO Pin programming doesnt work with Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I wanted to send electricity through a GPIO Pin (Raspberry Pi Pico) to power a small Motor (Just for fun) but the Programming doesn't work.

The Code:

```
import machine
import utime

motor = machine.Pin(7, machine.Pin.OUT)
print("init")

while True:
    print(motor.high())
```

But on the `motor.high()` its only prints `None` same with `motor.value(1)` or `motor.on()`. And I am not getting an Error in the console

I'm not the best with electricity so maybe it isn't the programming part, all I do is hold the wires of the motor against the connections of the Pico. But if i put i non Ground wire aigains the always running 3V Volt "Pin" the motors spins.

I am using a Pico with `MicroPython v1.19.1` and the IDE is Thonny

Comment: What were you expecting to be printed?  All three of those commands simply set a GPIO state, there is nothing meaningful for them to return.  (And please note that GPIO pins are COMPLETELY INAPPROPRIATE for driving a motor directly - they don't have the current capacity or the protection against inductive kickback to do that safely.)

Comment: Thank you I'll try it with a resistor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the rpi pico doesn't have enough power through gpio to run a motor on its
   own
2. neither `motor.high()` `motor.value(1)` nor `moter.on()` return a value
3. to make this work you need to connect a transistor to switch the power on and off
   [image]